# How to store Exec result to datetime variable where exec result has variable table name?

Tags: sql-server

How can I store my execution result in datetime variable?

My query look like this:

```
Declare @F VARCHAR(50) = (select replace ('H-10','-',''));
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
set @SQLQuery=
N'SELECT
   top 1 DATEADD(MINUTE, -330, time_stamp) as time
 FROM
  DMD_'+@F+'_DC_data
 ORDER BY
  time_stamp ASC';
DECLARE @SOR_time datetime
   
set @SOR_time=Exec (@SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way. Execute query result store into the table instead of assign to a variable.

```
Declare @F VARCHAR(50) = (select replace ('H-10','-',''));
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
set @SQLQuery=
N'SELECT
   top 1 DATEADD(MINUTE, -330, time_stamp) as time
 FROM
  DMD_'+@F+'_DC_data
 ORDER BY
  time_stamp ASC';

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (SOR_time datetime)
insert @TempTable 
exec (@SQLQuery)
select * from @TempTable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the *... execution result in datetime variable...*, one solution is to execute the generated statement using `sp_executesql` with an `OUTPUT` parameter:

```
DECLARE @F varchar(50) = (select replace ('H-10', '-', '')); 
DECLARE @SOR_time datetime  
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS nvarchar(500) 

SET @SQLQuery = 
   N'SELECT TOP 1 @SOR_time = DATEADD(MINUTE, -330, time_stamp) ' +
   N'FROM QUOTE_NAME(DMD_' + @F + '_DC_data) ' +
   N'ORDER BY time_stamp ASC'
; 

DECLARE @rc int
EXEC @rc = sp_executesql 
   @SQLQuery, 
   N'@SOR_time datetime OUTPUT', 
   @SOR_time OUTPUT
IF @rc <> 0 PRINT 'Error'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just assign to variable inside query if result set is just a single variable

```
Declare @F VARCHAR(50) = (select replace ('H-10','-',''));
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SOR_time DATETIME

set @SQLQuery=
N'SELECT
   top 1 @SOR_time = DATEADD(MINUTE, -330, time_stamp)
 FROM
  DMD_'+@F+'_DC_data
 ORDER BY
  time_stamp ASC';

-- PRINT @SQLQuery  

Exec (@SQLQuery)
SELECT @SOR_time
```

Comment: You need an `OUTPUT` parameter for this to work

Comment: not required. run and check

Comment: After removing the spurious `as time` alias, you will see it still doesn't work without `OUTPUT` you will get `Must declare the scalar variable "@SOR_time".` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f2adb250bebf77f515ca31bf58c47a9 Basically, the dynamic query is a different scope, so you need to redeclare the parameters and variables, and pass them back, as if it was a separate stored procedure

Comment: ok my mistake. was executing just printed query